# local PDF file on web view

Tags: android, parsing, webview

I have get data from server and parse in the data is mainly in html form and i want to show on web view, pdf,images,.doc,xls are in the html response i have to run this app in off line mode so i download all files and replace server location  to local file location.All running good but when i click on pdf file the file does not open..
I have just put sample code

```
html="<p><a href='file://storage/emulated/0/User/Uploads/greenergy-newsletter.pdf'><img src='file://storage/emulated/0/User/Uploads/download_pdf.jpg' alt='' width='147' height='133'/></a></p>";
browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", null, null);
```

I googled and i dont wanna use google docs.please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Android is Linux based, and on Linux path should start with 3 slashes.
So if your location is correct:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/User/Uploads/greenergy-newsletter.pdf
```

Also check permissions to read local file system

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```